# Issue with Citrix direct login in my application

Tags: api, rest, citrix

I am using Citrix direct login method in my application. This is my URL:

[https://api.citrixonline.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=password&client_id={API DeveloperKey}&username={username}&password={password}](https://api.citrixonline.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=password&client_id=%7BAPI%20DeveloperKey%7D&username=%7Busername%7D&password=%7Bpassword%7D)

But I always get the following response:

> { int_err_code: "InvalidLogin" msg: "Invalid userid or password"}

However, I can do it with a browser using this link:

[https://api.citrixonline.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={API Developer Key}](https://api.citrixonline.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=%7BAPI%20Developer%20Key%7D)

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use currect api developer key and make sure that the user name or password is correct